# XSL to select and group distinct data based on 3 different parameters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, oracle11g

I'm using XSL 1.0 and Xpath 1.0.

I'm new to XSL and XPath and there is this thing I'm trying to do in XSL using Oracle JDeveloper. I am selecting data from a table based on combination of 3 things that are "forename(mandatory), surname(can be null), and emp_type(can be null)". The query I used to retrieve data from table selects data for the provided "forename, surname(can be null) and emp_type(can be null)" and for the forename "Nina". "Nina" doesn't have a surname in the table as it is required to be retrieved by default however it may or may not have an "emp_type" What I want is to group data into distinct blocks with data for one particular combination of "forename, surname and emp_type" coming under one node of result after applying transformation. The data collection from table looks like the data below:

Data coming from table:

```
<OutputCollection>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname>Collins</surname>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description1</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment1</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname>Collins</surname>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description2</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment2</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname>Collins</surname>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description3</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment3</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description4</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment4</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description5</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment5</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description6</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment6</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description7</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment7</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description8</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment8</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description9</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment9</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description10</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment10</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description11</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment11</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description12</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment12</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description13</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment13</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description14</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment14</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description15</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment15</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description</descname>

<desc>Description16</desc>

<comment>comment16</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description18</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment18</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description19</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment19</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description20</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment20</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description21</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment21</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>

<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<descname>Description22</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment22</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description23</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment23</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description24</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment24</comment>

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>

<surname nil="true"/>

<emp_type nil="true"/>

<off_type nil="true"/>

<descname>Description25</descname>

<desc>Description</desc>

<comment>comment25</comment>

</Output>

</OutputCollection>
```

Requirement:

```
<Response_After_Applying_Transformation>

<Outputs>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname>Collins</surname>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<desc_groups>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description1</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment1</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description2</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment2</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description3</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment3</comment>
</desc_group>
</desc_groups>
.
.
.

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<desc_groups>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description4</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment4</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description5</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment5</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description6</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment6</comment>
</desc_group>
</desc_groups>
.
.
.


</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type/>
<off_type/>

<desc_groups>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description10</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment10</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description11</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment11</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description12</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment12</comment>
</desc_group>
</desc_groups>
.
.
.

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>

<desc_groups>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description13</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment13</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description14</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment14</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description15</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment15</comment>
</desc_group>
</desc_groups>
.
.
.

</Output>

<Output>

<forename>Nina</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type/>
<off_type/>

<desc_groups>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description23</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment23</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description24</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment24</comment>
</desc_group>
<desc_group>
<descname>Description25</descname>
<desc>Description</desc>
<comment>comment25</comment>
</desc_group>
</desc_groups>
.
.
.

</Output>

</Outputs>

</Response_After_Applying_Transformation>
```

In case all this is not possible with a single transformation please help me with a way to find out distinct combinations of "forename, surname and emp_type" so that I can use it in another transformation to get the required result.

Required Intermediate Response:

```
<Intermediate_Response>

<Intermediate_Result>
<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname>Collins</surname>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>
</Intermediate_Result>

<Intermediate_Result>
<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>
</Intermediate_Result>

<Intermediate_Result>
<forename>Anna</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type/>
<off_type/>
</Intermediate_Result>

<Intermediate_Result>
<forename>Nina</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type>Permanent</emp_type>
<off_type>PERM</off_type>
</Intermediate_Result>

<Intermediate_Result>
<forename>Nina</forename>
<surname/>
<emp_type/>
<off_type/>
</Intermediate_Result>

</Intermediate_Response>
```

Your help will be deeply appreciated. I'll be really grateful to you all.

Comment: No intermediate step is required. Here's how: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I'm not able to understand that. Please help me with it, I already read that. I will be really grateful to you if you can make me understand that. And please with some links so that I can make myself better in all the XML stuff like xsl, xpath etc. Could you let me know how can do this with this with Muenchian Method. I'll be really grateful.

Comment: "*I'm not able to understand that.*"  That's too bad. I don't know how to explain it any better myself. Try looking at the numerous examples of Muenchian grouping implementation here on SO.

Comment: Well thanks a lot. Actually I'm trying to learn but it was urgent for me that's why I put it here.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to group by forename, surname and emp_type. In which case you need to use a concatenated key to include all three fields

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="Output" use="concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type)" />
```

Note the use of the `|` character here. You can use anything, just as long as it doesn't occur in any of the three elements.

Then, to get the 'distinct' elements, you have to get the element that occurs first in the 'group' for it's particular combination of forename, surname and emp_type. You do this like so:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Output[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type))[1])]" />
```

And to get all the items within the group (for your `desc_group`), you can just use the key again

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type))">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="group" match="Output" use="concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type)" />

   <xsl:template match="Outputs">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Output[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type))[1])]" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Output">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="forename|surname|emp_type|off_type" />
         <desc_groups>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('group', concat(forename, '|', surname, '|', emp_type))">
               <desc_group>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="descname|desc|comment" />
               </desc_group>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </desc_groups>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The link to [Jeni's XSLT Pages: Grouping Using the Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html%20%22) is probably the definitive article on Muenchian Grouping (it comes out first when you Google "Muenchian grouping"), but it does take a while to get your head around it. So, re-read it, if you can! And try with maybe simpler examples (i.e. group on one element).